# "Environmentalist" VS "Eco-warrior"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

What do you normally call someone who is interested in environment and tries to avoid others from inflicting damage to it?

I know two options, but I have no idea if one of them has some extra qualities except those I mentioned or they are interchangeable!

> 1. ["Environmentalist"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/environmentalist) 
>     2. ["Eco-warrior"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/eco-warrior)

To me, they both mean the same and can be used interchangeably, though the latter seems to be a bit stilted and more serious.

Comment: They like to call themselves "eco-warriors" but they're not really warriors per se. They're mostly just angry teenagers. I would use "environmental activist".

Comment: How about "environmentalist" @Micah Windsor?

Comment: That works too, it's just not as common in my opinion. It is the better of your two.